# Adding Prefix to Name in lead using triggers

Tags: triggers, apex

whenever a new Lead Record is created, i want to add Prefix as 'Dr'.to each newly created record.Here is my code

```
trigger prefixdoc on Lead (before insert) {
   
  list<Lead>listlead = Trigger.new;
   
   for(lead l:listlead){
     l.firstname = 'Dr.'+l.firstname;
   }
}
```

Now if i create a record with

> Rosy as lastname
>
> The record is saved as Dr.nullRosy.

why am i getting that null...??
Can anyone please explain me ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system autocalculates the `Name` field on Contact and Lead by concatenating the fields `FirstName` and `LastName`, so `Firstame` is stored as `null` if you don't explicitly specify it. Since you're prepending a string before initializing a value for `FirstName`, it's including the literal value of null, casted to a String for UI uses.

Initialize a `FirstName` value and the null won't be included. Do you only want to add a "Dr." if FirstName is provided?

This prints "Dr.null":

```
Lead l = new Lead(LastName = 'Rosy', Company = 'Apple');
l.FirstName = 'Dr.' + l.FirstName;
insert l;
System.debug(l.FirstName);
```

and slightly redundant, but for illustration purposes but this prints "Dr."

```
Lead l = new Lead(LastName = 'Rosy', Company = 'Apple');
l.FirstName = '';
l.FirstName = 'Dr.' + l.FirstName;
insert l;
system.debug(l);
```

So your final code could look something like this:

```
trigger prefixdoc on Lead (before insert) {
  for (Lead l : Trigger.new){
    if (l.FirstName == null) {
      l.FirstName = '';
    }
    l.FirstName = 'Dr.'+ l.FirstName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

trigger lead prefix on Account (before insert) {

```
for(lead a: trigger.new)
{

a.name= 'Mr'+' ' +   a.name;
  }

}
```

this wil add mr in front of name field in lewad ..you can customize according to your requirement